# Why am I unable to reference html controls from code behind while using runat="server"?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <button type="button" id="serverbtn" name="serverbtn" runat="server" 
        OnClick="serverbtn_Click">Submit
        </button>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input id="servertxt" name="servertxt" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace WebApp
{ 
    public class ServerSide
    {        
        public void serverbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String txt = servertxt.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to asp.net and to building websites in general. I want to pass the text entered into an html input to the C# code behind for processing. From what I've read, adding the runat="server" allows these controls to be visible to the C#. However, the servertxt control says that it doesn't exist in the current context. This project uses the empty website in Visual Studio and not a webform/webapp. I added the html and C# file to the project manually. What am I missing here?

Comment: Need to see a more complete example of the .aspx page and code-behind. What you have here isn't a WebForms page, and WebPages / MVC doesn't work the same as WebForms (there's no code-behind file).

Comment: If you haven't yet, should probably start reading this (assuming WebForms is what you're doing): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/

Comment: So it sounds like I chose the wrong project type. From what you're saying I need to use Webforms or MVC to get an html page and a C# class to communicate? Because this was an empty website project, I just have an html page and a C# class file that are independent of each other. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: WebForms is the only ASP.NET version that has a code-behind file. It was intended as (basically) Windows Forms for the web. The MVC Framework sits on top of ASP.NET, but doesn't use a code-behind; pages (views) are independent of controllers (where your server code would live), but are linked by (mostly) convention. Explaining the difference and/or usage is too broad for Stack Overflow - you'd want to start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/overview) and work your way through the topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<input>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) is an HTML tag that is used for a form's data storage on client-side. But it isn't a server control. Moreover, there is no *runat* attribute for `<input>` element in [HTML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/the-input-element.html). You should use [`<asp:TextBox>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) server-side control instead. Also, if you want to handle button click event on the server-side then you have to use [`<asp:Button>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button(v=vs.110).aspx) control instead of [`<button>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) element.